# Use all of the requests to answer available at once on a question on Quora from the Google Chrome browser console

Tags: javascript, automation, browser-automation, google-chrome-console, quora

I often have to click 25 times on the blue button with a plus next to the suggested profiles that might answer the question I'm interested in on Quora.
It's boring.
[image: Screen capture of the Quora user interface to ask to answer]
What should I put in the google chrome console to automate this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you open the modal where you can request answers from other Quora users enter this in the browser console:

```
document.querySelectorAll(`[d='M21.106 11.553 5.08 3.54a.5.5 0 0 0-.698.605l2.148 6.443 5.511.919c.557.093.557.894 0 .986l-5.511.919-2.148 6.443a.5.5 0 0 0 .698.605l16.026-8.013a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.894Z']`).forEach(e=>e.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.click())
```

you don't even need to open the console if you add this as bookmark url:

```
javascript:(function(){document.querySelectorAll(`[d='M21.106 11.553 5.08 3.54a.5.5 0 0 0-.698.605l2.148 6.443 5.511.919c.557.093.557.894 0 .986l-5.511.919-2.148 6.443a.5.5 0 0 0 .698.605l16.026-8.013a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.894Z']`).forEach(e=>e.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.click())})()
```

Then you just have to click your bookmark to send the requests

It works on mobile too, if you search the bookmark from the request page and tap on it.

Comment: @iser11206537 It makes me very happy to read that you find my solution amazing. Enjoy!

Comment: @user11206537 Thank you for your consideration :)

Comment: @user11206537 I added the option to add the function into a bookmark to run the script without the need to open the console.

Comment: @Sun I edited the post with an updated version of the bookmarklet

Comment: Just verified it works. Thank you for the update. All the left forefinger clicking is really painful. Wish I could tip you 1000 of my reputation points.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to limit the clicking to the first 25? Sometimes the list is super long and you end up clicking more than 25 which cause temporary notifications to appear on screen. I wonder if Quora would frown upon this...?

Comment: @Sun you could do this :
`javascript:(
  function(){
    var requests = document.querySelectorAll('path[stroke-linecap='round']'); 
    for(
      var i = 0; 
      i < 50; 
      i++
    ){
      requests[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.click()
    }
  }
)()`
Modify 50 to 25 if it fails too often.

Comment: Thanks. I added your comment to the post. Some weirdness in the comment because of the backtick in the javascript. The edit I put in your post works for me.